# Export Python Arrays to Matlab

Tags: python, arrays, matlab

I am a beginner with Python and I am encountering the following problem.

I deal with sensors data. Each sensor gives me a np.array with **varying** size (n,p). For the moment, I just add the new array into a list, and then convert this list in a array, which gives an array of arrays.
I would like to export the final result (equivalent to a multi-dimensionnal array with variable size) in a written file that I want to be readable in Matlab to test advanced algorithms on it.
My question is the following : is there a better way to collect the data to export it in Matlab? And what could be a possible way to write a Matlab readable file from this multi-dimensional array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is a better way : use **[scipy](http://scipy.org/)** !!
Then you can use **[savemat method](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.io.savemat.html#scipy.io.savemat)** to "Save a dictionary of names and arrays into a MATLAB-style .mat file"
the code would be something like this:

```
import numpy, scipy.io
your_array = a multi dimential matrix
scipy.io.savemat('your direction and name', mdict={'arr': your_array})
```